# How can i make my output of prime decomposition more practical?

Tags: c

I made a program which decompose prime numbers in c :

```
int i = 2;

while (n != 1)
{
  while (n % i == 0)
  {
    printf("%d ", i);
    n = n / i;
  }

  i++;
}
```

and output for 36 would be :

```
2 2 3 3
```

How can i make it to be like:

```
2^2 * 3^2
```

Comment: Incidentally this process is known as _prime factorization_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
while (n != 1)
{
  int power  = 0;
  int factor = i;

  while (n % i == 0)
  {
    power = power + 1;
    n = n / i;
  }
  i++;
  if (power == 0) continue;

  if (power > 1)
    printf("%d^%d", factor, power);
  else
    printf("%d", factor);

  if (n != 1)
    printf(" * ");
  else
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: A neat solution would not print `2^1` but just `2` when `power == 1` at the time of printing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it's almost perfect, but I'm not sure about position of "i++" in your code, because when i try for example 7, the result always +1(8 for this example) How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Just introduce a counter and move the printout to the outer loop.

```
while (n != 1)
{
  int counter=0;
  while (n % i == 0)
  {
    counter++;
    n = n / i;
  }
  printf("%d^%d * ", i, counter);
  i++;
}
```

Note that this code will print zeros too, so an output could look like `2^2 * 3^0 * 4^0 * 5^3 *`. It will also print a trailing `*` in the end. I just showed the basic idea. Look at [sephiroth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58599413/6699433) for a better, but slightly more complicated, version.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i make my output of prime decomposition more practical?

Do not iterate `while (n != 1) { .... i++; }`.  This is is very inefficient when `n` is a large prime as only up to `sqrt(n)` iterations are needed rather than `n`.

When a factor is found, continue reducing `n` by that factor.  I recommend a helper function `factor_count()` to add clarity.  Return the number of times that factor was used.

Sample code

```
static int factor_count(int *n, int factor) {
  int count = 0;
  while (*n % factor == 0) {
    *n /= factor;
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}

void factorize(int n) {
  printf("%d: ", n);
  if (n < 2) {
    printf("%d", n);
  } else {
    const char *times = "";
    // only iterate until factor <= sqrt(n)
    for (int factor = 2; factor <= n / factor; factor++) {
      int count = factor_count(&n, factor);
      if (count) {
        printf("%s%d", times, factor);
        if (count > 1) {
          printf("^%d", count);
        }
        times = " * ";
      }
    }
    if (n > 1) {
      printf("%s%d", times, n);
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Test

```
int main() {
  factorize(0);
  factorize(1);
  factorize(2);
  factorize(12);
  factorize(61);
  factorize(3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3);
  factorize(2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11);
  factorize(INT_MAX);
  factorize(INT_MAX - 2);
  factorize(INT_MAX - 4);
  factorize(INT_MAX - 6);
}
```

Output

```
0: 0
1: 1
2: 2
12: 2^2 * 3
61: 61
243: 3^5
2310: 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11
2147483647: 2147483647
2147483645: 5 * 19 * 22605091
2147483643: 3 * 715827881
2147483641: 2699 * 795659
```